# Error when loading a javacpp and javcv

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, javacpp

A few weeks ago I found this tutorial on hand gesture detection for opencv and javacv. I started using the example but kept running into the same error over and over again.

Here is the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_objdetect in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
    at handDectector.Handy.<init>(Handy.java:32)
    at handDectector.Handy.main(Handy.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_objdetect248 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:481)
```

I read a lot of posts online related problems online related to this issue where people found the same javacpp and javacv file. I tried doing that a couple of times, but it didn't work.

Here is the code :

```
package handDectector; 

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.opencv.core.Core;

import java.io.*;

import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.*;
import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;



public class Handy extends JFrame 
{
  // GUI components
 private HandPanel handPanel;


  public Handy()
  {
    super("Hand Detector");

    Container c = getContentPane();
   c.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );   


    // Preload the opencv_objdetect module to work around a known bug.
    Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);

    handPanel = new HandPanel(); // the webcam pictures and drums appear here
    c.add( handPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
      { handPanel.closeDown();    // stop snapping pics, and any drum playing
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });

    setResizable(false);
    pack();  
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
  } // end of Handy()


  // -------------------------------------------------------

  public static void main( String args[] )
  {  

    new Handy();  

  }

} // end of Handy class
```

The problem lies in the opencv_obj file not being present.

I don't have much experience with this library at all. Is it possible if anyone could help me fix the problem? I know for sure there are posts on github and stackoverflow about the same exact problem... But they all use maven. Is it possible to do it without maven?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv#manual-installation) gives instructions on manual installation.

However I strongly suggest you to use `maven` or some dependency management tool. If you insist of doing it manually then you might want to try adding all the dependencies listed in `dependencies` section in this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/javacv-platform/1.3).